# Connect a router to a wifi repeater with a lan port

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My PS4, NAS, HTCP and Smart TV are two rooms away from my providers router.
It would be very difficult to get a LAN cable from the providers router to a router located where my PS4 etc. are located.

Now I want to buy a WIFI repeater with a LAN connector.
Is it possible to connect a router to the LAN connector of the Wifi repeater, so my PS4 etc. can connect to the internet?

So:
[web] connected to [provider router] has wifi to [wifi repeater] has lan cable to [asus router] has 4 lan cables to NAS, HTPC, Smart TV, PS4

Thinking of the "TP-LINK TL-WA850RE" wifi repeater.

Comment: I don't think you really want a Wi-Fi repeater, which will cut the bandwidth, at least, in half because Wi-Fi devices cannot both send and receive at the same time. It sounds like you want a wireless bridge to bridge the Wi-Fi to wired devices.

Comment: ...unless they were specifically designed for that, and have a second radio for the uplink.

Comment: WDS works well if you can configure it in both routers. I do not recommend the fake NAT Wifi repeating that so-called "wifi extenders" do. It breaks multicast. It breaks non-IP traffic. And it just tends to work very, very badly. Either run a wire, extend over powerline, or use devices *on both sides* that are intended to bridge.